# A question about subexponential growth about group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Recall a group $\Gamma$ is said to have ***subexponential growth*** if lim sup$|E^{n}|^{1/n}=1$ for every finite subset $E\subset \Gamma. (E^{n}=\{g_{1}g_{2}...g_{n}: g_{i}\in E\}.)$

My question is: Can we prove all abelian groups have subexponential growth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider any subset $E_m$ of your abelian group of size $m$. Then since the group is abelian, $|E_m^n|$ is no more than the number of ways you can choose $m$ non-negative integers to sum up to $n$, which is${{n+m-1} \choose {m-1}}$ which is no more than than $(n+m-1)^{m-1}$. Since the exponent is a constant, you will get $\lim_{n \to \infty}(n+m-1)^{(m-1)/n} = 1$. So an abelian group is indeed subexponential.

Comment: what do you mean "size m"?